# Save or Merge Patch Entity

Tags: spring-data-rest

I want following functionality in spring data rest.

If I post to a collection resource end point, server should check if the object exists. if it exists already it should perform the same functionality as it does with merge-patch on item resource. If object does not exist already it should create it.

Is this achievable in spring data rest. If so then how?

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible in your use case, you might want to use PUT instead of POST, as PUT should work as you expected.

**Solution with POST**

You can achieve the desired behavior with [Spring Data REST Event handlers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler).

Just create a Handler method which accepts your entity and annotate it with `@HandleBeforeCreate`. In this method, you can implement your behavior, i.e. check if the object exists and update it manually or just do nothing and let the Spring Data REST handle the entity creation.

```
@RepositoryEventHandler 
public class EntityEventHandler {

   @Autowired
   private EntityService entityService;

   @HandleBeforeCreate
   public void handleEntityCreate(Entity e) {
      if (entityService.exists(e)) {
         entityService.update(e);
      }
   }
}
```

EDIT:
I just realized that you would also need to stop the create event after your update. You might try throwing a custom Exception and Handling it to return 200 and the updated entity.